# Flex item disappear on width shrink even with flex-shirnk set to 0

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm building a ReactJS grid component that will allow me to resize its width. The resize is done by clicking on the `grip` div of the component and dragging it left or right. My code:

```
class Cell extends Component {

  handleGrip = event => {
    if (this.props.onGrip) this.props.onGrip(event);
  };

  render() {
    let gripComponent = (
      <div
        onMouseDown={this.handleGrip}
        className="cell-grip"
      />
    );

    let width = this.props.width;

    return (
      <div
        className={"cell-container"}
        style={{ width: width }}
      >
        <div className="cell-content">{this.props.children}</div>
        {gripComponent}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cell;
```

SCSS Class:

```
.cell-container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid $ux-theme-color-border;
    margin: 0 -1px 0 0;
    background-color: $ux-theme-color-white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.cell-content {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.cell-grip {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 5px;
    min-width: 5px;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    background-color: $ux-theme-color-border;
}
```

(The full widht calculation and event handling is not shown here)

All working fine, except for one thing. The `grip` component is rendered in a flexbox right positioned to its content. When the width gets to small, the `grip` is not rendered and therefore I cannot select it any more. This causes me to be unable to resize the cell if it gets too small, as there is no `grip` shown to select. Check images before and after:

Before:

[image: Before]

After resize:

[image: After]

The `grip` disappear once the width of the cell gets smaller than the width of the content (`cell-content`) (first flex item do show).

How can I prevent this to happen and guarantee that the `grip` will be shown on any width?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle / codepen? Do any answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39765052/3597276